# Constant contact and Theme my login

Tags: php, forms, constantcontact

I want to integrate theme my login with Constant contact but theme mylogin has its own `id`,`name`,`classes` on its field.

It also have its own form action. Usually i extract the form from an embed post and get the `id` and `names` and `form action` so that i can manipulate the forms but this time it is different  and i dont know what to dd.

example input in TML:

```
<input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_email' ); ?>" size="20" />
```

example form action on TML:

```
 <form name="registerform" id="registerform<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'register' ); ?>" method="post">
```

example input in the embed code:

```
 <input data-id="Email Address:input" type="text" name="email" value="" maxlength="80">
```

example form action of embed:

```
<form data-id="embedded_signup:form" class="ctct-custom-form Form" name="embedded_signup" method="POST" action="https://visitor2.constantcontact.com/api/signup">
```